# Pattern working on regex101 but not with Google Script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to match some paragraphs in Google Docs but the pattern that I wanted to use for it doesn't match the string when run inside a Google Script. However, it works properly on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jzAlOv/1) so I guess I'm missing something. Do you know what?

This is a sample of what I have:

```
function test() {
  var str = "brown fox → jumps over the lazy dog";
  var definitionRe = new RegExp('([\w\s]+)\s+[\u2192]\s+(.+)', 'g');
  var definitionMatch = definitionRe.exec(str); // null

  var dummy = "asdf"; // makes the debugger happy to break here
}
```

Comment: I think you need to escape your escape patterns, so `\w\s` becomes `\\w\\s` and so on...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it's 2 slashes

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks I updated it

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn wow, you're right! It's working now! Thanks ;-)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate so it's been closed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a string regex such as `new RegExp(...)`, you need to escape your `\`'s, so then the following:

```
var definitionRe = new RegExp('([\w\s]+)\s+[\u2192]\s+(.+)', 'g');
```

Will become an escaped version like this:

```
var definitionRe = new RegExp('([\\w\\s]+)\\s+[\\u2192]\\s+(.+)', 'g');
```

Otherwise you can do a non string version, but you then can no longer concatenate values to the string (If that is something you would like):

```
var definitionRe = /([\w\s]+)\s+[\u2192]\s+(.+)/g;
```